# Why is TOAD faster than my java code?

Tags: java, select, count, performance, toad

I want to execute a select query and be able to get the count of the results, without using "COUNT(*)", like TOAD does. The concept is to give the option to the user to input any 'select query' he wants and to count the number of the results for him.

```
try {
   selectStatement = globalConnection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
   ResultSet selectResultSet = selectStatement.executeQuery(selectStatementString);
   selectResultSet.last();
   int countOfResults = selectResultSet.getRow();
   writeInLabel(kllStatusLabel, "Count Finished: Found " + countOfResults + " Inserts");
} catch (SQLException ex) {
   writeInLabel(kllStatusLabel, "Error executing select query.");
}
```

This code delays much in line: "selectResultSet.last();".
TOAD does it with much less delay. (Right-Click -> Record Count).
Even when I scroll the results table all the way down in TOAD it does it faster.

How does TOAD get the record count?

OK I got it, I will use count(*) and have a second ResultSet to show my results.

```
ResultSet selectResultSet = selectStatement.executeQuery("select count(*) from (" + selectStatementString + ")");
int countOfResults = 0;
if (selectResultSet.next()){
   countOfResults = selectResultSet.getInt(1);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered that TOAD does sequential selects, that is, it gets the first 500 records and display them, while you may browse, it is still looking for more data? In other words, have you considered that TOAD is multithreading and except mentioned otherwise, I don't see any multithreading in your code?

Comment: I am not talking about results, only count of results. That is what I am trying to say. Even the simple record count is fast in TOAD. Sorry, I didn't give all my code. I am using threads in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TOAD is probably selecting the `@@rowcount` or some other DB specific result metadata.
If you want the size of the result, ask the DB for it explicitly (with `COUNT()`)

If you're using mysql then you can use `ROW_COUNT()`.

Answer (score 0):

Better keep the `COUNT()` close to the database providing a separate stored procedure exclusively containing the select with the count, and access that stored procedure from your code whenever you need it.